# Appreject or not with payment process

Tags: iphone, database, paypal, appstore-approval

I have an app with upload some products in database. I have registration page in my website and also app have registration. User can able to register and upload products. If registration finish it generate username and password. If i use this login details it goes to profile page, here user can able to upload products. After uploading 3 products i set limitation for buy. If user use payment for more than 3 images it will allow to upload next image. This part of payment is active via website not app. Is appStore reject my app for this kind of things? I didn't use In-App-Purchase. Only use limit for 3 products after payment done able to upload more than 3 products. Then in app i can get all the products from database and displays in mobile viewController.

Comment: Are you using Paypal Mobile Express Checkout service for the Payment??

Comment: Paypal mobile Express Checkout is only for apps. Im asking to website not an inside app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right answer to your question is consult with Apple.

In my experience, if you are unlocking some feature in you application upon payment, your app needs to do this via In-app purchase. In your case, upon payment you are enabling user the ability to upload more than 3 images from the application, then I suggest you should include In-app purchase.

Hope that helps!

Comment: @user2674668 Does your application takes user to payment page on website?

Comment: Yes. But the payment process not through app. It's through website paypal some other

Comment: @user2674668 That's not allowed, because your app cannot direct user to a website which asks for payment to unlock some feature. There are chances this can get rejected. You should post query in [Apple devforum](https://developer.apple.com/devforums/).

Comment: It won't direct user to website from app. If you register then login link with mail send to user email. User won't allow upload or payment check from app. It appear only through website